# Bash script : Storing command with spaces and arguments in variable and then executing

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Been banging my head against the wall for a couple hours so time to call in the experts.  Writing a small script to run some reports on one of my office's systems and I was asked to take care of a Bash script for it.   The program called "auto_rep" takes various options such as "-t" to run one task (to generate one type of report) and a "-1" to exit after one task.  The options are separated by spaces when running the command from command-line.  The command works directly from command line but I cannot get it to work from a script...

Below is the snippet of code causing me issues:

```
cmd=$(auto_rep -t createfin1report -1)
echo "running ${cmd} command..."
echo
eval $cmd
```

The problem is when I run the script, only the "auto_rep" part of the command (from $cmd variable) is run; basically running the program without any options.  And it creates tons of reports without the "-t createfin1report -1" part of the command (yikes!).  Glad I only tried it on our test system.

Anyone have any tips to help me out?   Is my approach way off?   BTW - had tried just storing the command in a non-array (cmd="auto_rep -t createfin1report -1") and that was causing me other headache with a "command not found" errors :)...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Use an array](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for the command and arguments.

Comment: See [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) And avoid `eval`, it's a massive bug magnet.

Comment: BTW, `cmd=$(somecommand)` *runs* the command, and stores *its output* (not the command itself) in `cmd` -- is that what you intended here?

Comment: @GordonDavisson, yup you're right.  that was a mistake I had.  I want the command in the cmd variable, not the result.

Comment: One other question @GordonDavisson.  If I were to store the entire command in an array like cmd=(auto_rep -t createfin1report -1), would I basically be able to run the command with just... ${cmd[@]} ?  Thanks again!

Comment: You should double-quote the array reference, like `"${cmd[@]}"`. Otherwise, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Save output to an array, then executing this array.

```
declare -a cmd
cmd=( $(auto_rep -t createfin1report -1) )
echo Executing: "${cmd[@]}"
"${cmd[@]}"
```

Please make sure the output is a valid command, and spaces have been correctly placed in double-quotes.